# Type Error: Float object is not callable

Tags: python

Getting the error in python when i am executing `max(2,3)`

```
>>> max(2,3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   file "<console>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

Is there any syntax problem ?

Comment: Please add raw text in your question instead of image.

Comment: You probably did somewhere above this line `max = 1.0` or similar.

Comment: Title of the question is the error when i am trying max(2,3) in python and that i captured. @ Tanveer Alam

Answer (score 12):

The code looks ok. You probably assigned some value to `max` before it.

```
>>> max(2, 3)
3
>>> max = 3.4
>>> max(2, 3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

If you did not explicitly assign anything to `max`, the problem may be in  a file you imported.

Answer (score 9):

Somewhere in your code you have put

```
max = some number
```

and now you are trying to use the `max` function after having bound the name `max` to a `float`. This is why you should always be careful of variable names

```
>>> max = 9.0
>>> max(2, 3)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    max(2, 3)
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

You could hack yourself out of this

```
>>> max = __builtins__.max
>>> max
<built-in function max>
>>> max(2, 3)
3
```

However you should never do this, just chose a different variable name such as `max_num`

Answer (score 0):

Actually the max() function takes "iterator " as the parameter and returns the maximum value, It is very flexible functions and accepts arguments in the form of:

- integers:

  ```
  maximum = max(2,1,4,5,6,9)
  print maximum
  ```

  - lists:

    maximum = max([2,1,4,5,6,9])

    print maximum
  - strings:

    maximum = max("214569")

    print maximum

so these are only some ways of using this function, and yes you can use the max function for the floating numbers in the same way. 
maximum = max(1.3,1.5,2.6,4.6)
print maximum

but you cannot pass a single float value or integer value to the function, You should pass any iterable object, with length greater than 1.

And you should avoid using these inbuilt functions as variable names

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think OP indeed called `max` with two ints: `2` and `3`.

Comment: Yeah but he uploaded an image first which was not clear,so , I was just exploring any possible causes for the same issue :)